# Ошибка при установке Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

При установке gulp в папку в командной строке пишет такие ошибки:

> *npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8:* graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
>
> *npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2:* lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained.   Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
>
> *npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3:* graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.

Как это исправить ?

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле, это не *ошибки* а *предупреждения* о том, что зависимости одного из модулей объявлены устаревшими. Если ваш проект не использует указанные модули с указанными версиями напрямую (через `package.json`), то вы сами не сможете ничего *исправить*.

Вместо этого, вам стоит сделать следующее:

1. Обновить используемые зависимости. Возможно, проблема уже решена.
2. Если после п.1 все равно выводятся предупреждения, стоит оповестить авторов модулей, использующих "протухшие" зависимости, о проблеме.
3. Поскольку `WARN` это всего лишь предупреждения, последнее, что вам осталось - это просто расслабиться.

Если же вас все равно смущает вывод предупреждений (в котором нет ничего страшного), можете запускать `npm install` с флагом `--loglevel=error`, как советует [@Darth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/32977/darth) в соседнем ответе.

Comment: подскажите, как обновить зависимости  ?

Comment: @SvArt713 https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Comment: @SvArt713, а еще можно использовать `npm update`. Еще можно сделать `npm outdated` чтобы понять, что из ваших зависимостей нужно обновлять, в `package.json` а дальше уже по ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Запускайте `npm install` с флагом `--silent` или `--loglevel=error`.
Или настройте его -  `npm config set loglevel error`

Comment: Это не исправит проблемы, а всего лишь скроет.

Comment: @D-side автор вопроса вполне конкретно написал - в консоль выводятся предупреждения, как это исправить? ни о каких проблемах в вопросе речи не было.

Comment: А вот это знать наверняка нельзя. "Это" это "то, что пишет", или "то, что в предупреждениях"? При этом если просто скрыть предупреждения, потом они вырастут в проблемы.

Comment: @D-side я использую галп в одном из проектов, все работает без проблем, это я знаю наверняка. Варнинги при установке галпа (как и многих других модулей с большим количеством зависимостей) - вполне обыденное явление, до ошибок они практически никогда не дорастают. В любом случае, ТС вряд ли будет править сам галп, так что все, чем ему можно помочь - это убрать предупреждения

Comment: Вот это всё стоит добавить в ответ в качестве объяснения, почему глушить предупреждения тут позволительно. Потому что это плохая практика: предупреждения существуют не просто так.